# Как избавиться от провалов в id? sql

Tags: java, sql, база-данных

Здравствуйте, есть таблица, id генерируется базой данных, после удаления строки образуется провал пример:

```
ID name
1  vlad
2  sergey
3  ivan
5  tolik
8  gesha
```

как этого избежать и можно ли это исправить в существующей таблице?

---

Благодарю всех за помощь!

Comment: Не надо избегать. Пусть себе образуются

Comment: @Sergey у меня генерируется случайное число и программа должна из базы доставать запись с этим айдишником, при этом провале на весь экран ошибки выскакивают, бывает даже много ошибок.Хотелось бы всё по фен-шую.

Comment: @user254236 генерируйте случайное число от `0` до `кол-во записей - 1` включительно, после чего просто берите такую запись из таблицы с помощью `LIMIT X, 1`. Так как число случайное, то сортировать таблицу по какому-то полю при этом смысла нет.

Comment: По феншую - ID сам по себе, а для выборки случайной записи заводится поле с непрерывной нумерацией, регулярно пересчитываемое. А если записей немного, то можно и `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> у меня генерируется случайное число и программа должна из базы
>   доставать запись с этим айдишником, при этом провале на весь экран
>   ошибки выскакивают, бывает даже много ошибок.Хотелось бы всё по
>   фен-шую

Если вам нужно выбрать случайную запись из таблицы, поручите это СУБД, так будет по фен-шую.

**PostgreSQL и SQLite:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1
```

**MySQL:**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1
```

**MS SQL Server:**

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM table_name ORDER BY NEWID()
```

**Oracle:**

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT column FROM table_name ORDER BY dbms_random.value) WHERE rownum = 1
```

Comment: В андроиде вроде MySQL зачем эти три варианта?

Comment: @Flippy во-первых, у вопроса нет тегов указывающих на используемую СУБД или операционную систему. Нет этой информации и в тексте вопроса. Во-вторых, Android использует SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Да, по id вы не сможете с уверенностью забирать запись, так как могут быть дыры. Их не надо "заделывать", это основа структуры SQL, почитайте. Считаю, что все колонки-велосипеды с номерами "без дыр" - огромный костыль. Как вы будете обновлять их номера при удалении самой первой записи, если их всего под миллион? 999999 запросов `update`?

Предлагаю, следующее. Не проще ли сразу получать рандомную запись из таблицы?

```
Cursor randomCursor = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { /* тут все колонки */ }, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "1");
if(cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    randomCursor.moveToFirst();
}
//берем из курсора данные рандомной записи
```

Если записей очень много, то операция может занять много времени. Подойдет для мелких таблиц. В случае работы с большими данными, я думаю, что лучше будет передавать массив не всех колонок, а только колонки с айдишником (`BaseColumns._ID`). А потом уже по полученному рандомному `id` через `where` выполнить второй запрос, уже получив все колонки. Примерно так:

```
Cursor randomId = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID }, null, null, null, null, "RANDOM()", "1");
    if(randomId != null && randomId.getCount() > 0) {
        //удалено. Курсор и так содержит одну запись
        //randomCursor.moveToFirst();
        int id = randomId.getInt(BaseColumns._ID);
        Cursor randomRow = db.query(DB_TABLE, new String[] { /* а вот тут уже все колонки */ }, BaseColumns._ID + "=?", new String[] { Integer.toString(id) }, null, null, null);
        //в курсоре randomRow лежит рандомная запись, получаем значения в колонках и используем
    }
```

Я думаю что так правильнее и будет быстрее, если это не так, поправьте меня в комментариях

Answer (score 0):

А для чего это исправлять? Ты добавляешь запись в таблицу, она получает уникальный номер. Инкремент сделал **+1**. Ты удаляешь эту запись - инкремент не изменился.

Если ты *запариваешься* по этому поводу, то:

1. При записи/удалении записей выбираем все записи
2. Транкейт этой таблицы
3. Изменение начального инкремент на 1
4. Заливаем обратно эти данные.

Но этот план, он **нецелесообразен**.

Comment: Нецелесообразные решения в ответе?

Comment: Да, это просто тебе как решение, может быть это будет тебе толчком. У меня была такая проблема: я получал справочники, один текст, ни одного целочисленного значения. Чтобы разнообразить и украсить таблу, я при получении справочников, генерировал уникальные айдишники, чистил таблу и заливал новые данные. Но в данном случае ты придираешься к тому, что у тебя, например, таблица называется "users", а должна быть "Users", имхо.

Comment: Триггер на insert написать и использовать вместо sequence :-) Но блин...
Можно еще поставить триггер на delete, и складывать освободившиеся id и таблицу-очередь, а триггер на insert мог бы из очереди брать... а если очередь пуста - автоинкремент по MAX(id)

Comment: Нарушать порядок id не стоит, ни в коем случае. Я в свое время тоже этим вопросом задался, мне обьяснил очень ограмотно @pavlofff, теперь и я с ним за одно

Answer (score -1):

Предлагаю вот такой вариант:

1. Вытаскиваем список **id** в массив типа **int[]**
2. Генерируем уникальное число от **0** до **int[].size - 1**
3. По индексу вытаскиваем **id**
4. Делаем запрос к БД.

Такой подход защищает от пробелов в **id** по крайней мере если в этот момент времени не было delete row